# What do white and black memory locks mean?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm trying to upgrade the memory on my PC. After opening up the tower, I found 2 memory slots, and one has black locks around it.

I did some Googling on the web said if the *slots* have the same colors, they're for dual channel RAMs. But it looks like my motherboard only has 2 slots.

What's special about the slot with black locks? Is there anything I need to be aware of?

[image]

Comment: I believe they are to distinguish channels, so if you had four slots, 1 and 3 would be white, and 2 and 4 would be black. I've seen them as black and blue, or other colors as well, but always alternating, so that says "channel" to me. in that case, populating an even number of black and white chips and are balanced in size, then the sysetm will run in dual-channel mode.

Comment: per your edit, the plastic slot covers that mobo manufacturers put on their boards all come from the same places, whether the system has 2, 4, 6, or 8 slots. a 2-slot system benefits from dual-channel memory access as much as a 4 slot one, so I don't see why your 2-slot board wouldn't alternate colors as well. I think you are overthinking this. just follow the same rules you would to get dual-channel working properly (balance in number and size of chips on each channel).

Comment: Your motherboard or system manual should tell you what, if any, significance the different slot colours have.